# Display Hindi Characters on android App

Tags: java, android, fonts, properties, hindi

I have created a document in hindi language using google indic keyboard ( I am not sure what font the characters are in)

I want to create property files for various language and want to display content as it is.

suppose I have following file

hindi.properties

```
kabir=समाज सुधारक
```

english.properties

```
kabir=Socoal Activist
```

Now I want to display these texts Irrespective of font whether installed or not.

I got some answers on stackoverflow like setting the hindi font something like this -

```
textview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Hindi.ttf"));
```

But this donesn't work for me as I don't know the font google indic keyboard uses.

Anyway I am looking for a generic solution that does not require any fonts.

Comment: [Localizing with Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Hindi make new folder inside res – values-hi/strings.xml put your all Hindi content in this and by default values/string.xml support English language.

Call `changeLocale(lang)` method whenever you want to change the language

for Hindi `changeLocale("hi");//Change Locale on selection basis`

for English  `changeLocale("en");//Change Locale on selection basis`

//Change Locale

```
public void changeLocale(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
   Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);//Set Selected Locale
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);//set new locale as default
    Configuration config = new Configuration();//get Configuration
    config.locale = myLocale;//set config locale as selected locale
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());//Update the config
}
```

Comment: I can try this. But my data is in properties file not in xml. Basically I want to write only in property files and display content as it is.

Comment: okay please go through this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/999726/Localization-with-Java-Property-Files may be this will help you